# How to mark a starting of a line when given string was found using swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I want to Mark the starting of the line with some symbol(like ->) whenever given string was found.It will mark all the lines when the given find string appear.I want to tried that,It was  shows the find string but I don't get idea of how to mark.Please give me some suggestions.Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
public class Mark extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Mark() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void markAll(JTextComponent component,String patteren){
        try {
            Document doc=component.getDocument();
            String text=component.getText(0,doc.getLength());
            int pos=component.getCaretPosition();
            if (pos==doc.getLength()) {
                pos=0;
            }
            int index=text.toUpperCase().indexOf(patteren.toUpperCase(),pos);
            if (index>=0) {

                component.setSelectionStart(index);
                component.setSelectionEnd(index+patteren.length());
                component.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);  
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        searchField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        mark = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        textPane = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mark.setText("Mark");
        mark.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                markActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(textPane);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                .addComponent(searchField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 88, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addComponent(mark)
                .addContainerGap(155, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(searchField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(mark))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 216, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void markActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

            markAll(textPane,searchField.getText());
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mark.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mark.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mark.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mark.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Mark().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JButton mark;
    private javax.swing.JTextField searchField;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane textPane;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Use a row header concept, creating a custom component that allows you to render a mark within the row header of a `JScrollPane`. For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766588/make-jscrollpane-control-multiple-components/21767752#21767752)

Comment: can you provide an example.

Comment: Like the one linked in the comment?