# JTextArea line counter text is not properly aligning in vertical orientation

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I tried to horizontally align text, from right to left, for linecounter textarea, and it worked but then I got a problem with vertical text alignment, it is not aligning properly with a textEditor line.

Below is screenshot of how it looks like and full code:

[image]

As you can see, for left to right, text area for line counter is in a line with textEditor textarea, but as I changed orientation right to left for line counter, it is not in the same line.

CODE:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Element;

public class LineNumbering extends JFrame {

    private static JTextArea jta;
    private static JTextArea lines;

    public LineNumbering() {
        super("Line Numbering Example");
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new LineNumbering();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();
        jta = new JTextArea();
        lines = new JTextArea("1");
        lines.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        lines.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        lines.setEditable(false);

        jta.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public String getText() {
                int caretPosition = jta.getDocument().getLength();
                Element root = jta.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
                String text = "1" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                for (int i = 2; i < root.getElementIndex(caretPosition) + 2; i++) {
                    text += i + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                }
                return text;
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                lines.setText(getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                lines.setText(getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                lines.setText(getText());
            }

        });

        jsp.getViewport().add(jta);
        jsp.setRowHeaderView(lines);
        jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        frame.add(jsp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, is there maybe other way or a fix to align this text from right to left for line counter ?

Comment: Maybe you should consider something more like [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766588/make-jscrollpane-control-multiple-components/21767752#21767752)

Comment: I will take a look at it. Thank you.