# JScrollPane dynamic RowHeader out of sync when resizing

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I want to implement a `TextArea` with a sidebar that shows the index of the leftmost character in each line of a wrapped text. This is implemented with a `JScrollPane` using `RowHeader` showing a `JTextPane` for the numbers and `Viewport` showing a `JTextArea` for the sequence.

All works well except that the `RowHeader` and `Viewport` are out of sync when resizing horizontally. In the following SSCCE it also happens at startup.

The picture illustrates this: The cursor of the `JTextArea` is at the first position while the lower end of `JTextPane` is shown.

I know it has something to do with the `JTextPane` changing its content dynamically because it works with static content.

Is it possible to prevent this odd behaviour?

[image]

```java
package main;

import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Utilities;

public class SequenceAreaExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(150, 200);

        SequenceArea sequenceArea = new SequenceArea();
        frame.add(sequenceArea);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
        sequenceArea.setText(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(200, "a")));
    }
}

class SequenceArea extends JScrollPane implements ComponentListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JTextArea text;
    private JTextPane numbers;

    // FIXME text and numbers are out of sync when resizing horizontally
    SequenceArea() {
        text = new JTextArea();
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setEnabled(true);
        text.addComponentListener(this);

        numbers = new JTextPane();
        numbers.setEnabled(false);

        setViewportView(text);
        setRowHeaderView(numbers);
    }

    void updateNumbers() {
        StringBuilder newNumbers = new StringBuilder();

        int length = text.getText().length();
        int index = 0;

        while (index < length) {
            try {
                int start = Utilities.getRowStart(text, index);
                int end = Utilities.getRowEnd(text, index);

                newNumbers.append(start);
                newNumbers.append('\n');

                index = end + 1;
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                break;
            }
        }

        numbers.setText(newNumbers.toString());
    }

    void setText(String t) {
        text.setText(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        updateNumbers();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert here but I'd probably try to build that myself, i.e. wrap the text pane and area with a panel and put that into the scroll pane.

Comment: For sanity, I might do something more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766588/make-jscrollpane-control-multiple-components/21767752#21767752)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment I tried to build an alternative solution with the row header being part of the viewport and it seems to work fine so far. (Btw, kudos for adding a SSCCE right at the start)

```
JPanel panel = new ScrollablePanel();        
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

//can be reused as constraints are only read when adding components
GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

//components should take all vertical space if possible.
constraints.weighty = 1.0;

//components should expand even if it doesn't need more space
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

//add the numbers component 
panel.add(numbers, constraints );

//add specific constraints for the text component        
//text takes as much of the width as it can get
constraints.weightx = 1.0;

//numbers component seems to have some insets so add 2px at the top to get better alignment - could be done differently as well
constraints.insets = new Insets(2, 0, 0, 0);
panel.add(text, constraints);
    
setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    
setViewportView(panel);
```

For this to work properly you also need to use a panel that's aware of scrolling and able to adjust its dimensions to the viewport:

```
class ScrollablePanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        //the panel prefers to take as much height as possible
        return new Dimension(getPreferredSize().width, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return 1;
    }

    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return 1;
    }

    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return true;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Putting both components into a JPanel inside the JScrollPane viewport fixes the scrolling issue. But is there now a way to get the JTextArea to expand in y direction to viewport size as before?

Comment: @user2011659 you could play around with methods like `getPreferredSize()` etc. which report size preferences to the layout manager. One option might be to return `true` from `getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()` and `new Dimension(getPreferredSize().width, Integer.MAX_VALUE)` from `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`. Then change the constraints for the components in the panel, i.e. add `weighty=1.0` for both and `anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTH` for at least the numbers component (although adding it for both shouldn't do any harm) (edited the answer to reflect this).

Comment: I only changed `getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()` to return `((JViewport)getParent()).getHeight() > getPreferredSize().height` after sanity check. Now it works and looks good. Thanks.